# My PC plugged into my AV receiver over HDMI flashes black repeatedly. How can I diagnose and fix?

Tags: video, graphics-card, hdmi, intel-graphics, av-receiver

With my PC (Dell Optiplex 7050 with Intel HD 530 GPU) plugged into my receiver (Yamaha RX-V6A), the display flashes black for two seconds every five seconds! If I unplug receiver power and restart, it's fixed for a while, but comes back every few days. Any ideas?

I'm using this with an HDMI output. Same thing happens whether I set the PC display output to 4k or 1080p. It happens even on the computer's boot screen and BIOS menu.

Note that I see a few flashes when I plug this PC into my Viewsonic 4k monitor, but nothing persistent like this.

I've tried scratch installing Windows 10 and updating the GPU driver.

Any ideas how to diagnose this or what might be causing it?

Comment: Have you tried a different cable?

Comment: That receiver is affected by a chipset bug, supposedly only impacts certain resolution and refresh combinations, but see for example: https://www.flatpanelshd.com/news.php?subaction=showfull&id=1619588759

Comment: Thanks @york. I've tried setting the output to different resolutions. None of the resolutions the PC can output are the ones reported to have the bug. No resolution fixes the problem.